# Change wp_woocommerce_session_ Cookie

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, session-cookies

Woocoomerce sets the Cookie wp_woocommerce_session_ , the duration of this cookie is 2 days. It contains a unique code for each customer so that it knows where to find the cart data in the database for each customer.

How can it set the duaration to 7 days, so that the cart data is not deleted after 2 days?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'wc_session_expiration', function(){
    return 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
});
```

You'll find the source for that filter over [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/includes/class-wc-session-handler.php#L164).